# distance_of_time_in_words and then remove the word "about"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, time

I have this code:

```
    = distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, real_time + 0.seconds, true)
```

Which generates also like:

```
about 15 hours
less than
```

**Is there a way to remove the word "About" from the results?** Already searched a lot but cannot find any info, the function in itself is great it throws back hours, minutes, seconds, etc. so great but the worst "about" has to go! Anyone knows how?

Comment: Beware – removing the words "about", "less than", "over" and "almost" means that your timestamps become a little bit less true. Was something updated "1 year ago" if it's 729 days old? Consider shortening "about" to "~", "less than" and "almost" to "<", and "over" to ">".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, real_time + 0.seconds, true).gsub('about ','')`

look [here](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001538) for more information

try a helper (put this code in app/helpers/application_helper.rb)

```
def remove_unwanted_words string
  bad_words = ["less than", "about"]

  bad_words.each do |bad|
    string.gsub!(bad + " ", '')
  end

  return string
end
```

in bad words you can define strings which you want to have removed from that string.
user it like this:

`<%= remove_unwanted_words distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, real_time + 0.seconds, true) %>`

Comment: thx i didn't thought of cutting the word just out, also I need to remove the text "less than" could you provide example on how to remove multiple texts? Thx I'm still learning for

Comment: Beware – this solution will cause you grief if you need to translate your site into a non-English language.

Comment: I would highly recommend the `scope` option instead. Docs for scope option at the bottom: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words

Answer (score 21):

Since `distance_of_time_in_words` uses localization keys, you can simply override them to achieve what you want in an I18n-safe way:

**config/locales/en.yml:**

```
en:
  # Used in distance_of_time_in_words(), distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(), time_ago_in_words()
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      half_a_minute: "half a minute"
      less_than_x_seconds:
        one:   "1 second" # default was: "less than 1 second"
        other: "%{count} seconds" # default was: "less than %{count} seconds"
      x_seconds:
        one:   "1 second"
        other: "%{count} seconds"
      less_than_x_minutes:
        one:   "a minute" # default was: "less than a minute"
        other: "%{count} minutes" # default was: "less than %{count} minutes"
      x_minutes:
        one:   "1 minute"
        other: "%{count} minutes"
      about_x_hours:
        one:   "1 hour" # default was: "about 1 hour"
        other: "%{count} hours" # default was: "about %{count} hours"
      x_days:
        one:   "1 day"
        other: "%{count} days"
      about_x_months:
        one:   "1 month" # default was: "about 1 month"
        other: "%{count} months" # default was: "about %{count} months"
      x_months:
        one:   "1 month"
        other: "%{count} months"
      about_x_years:
        one:   "1 year" # default was: "about 1 year"
        other: "%{count} years" # default was: "about %{count} years"
      over_x_years:
        one:   "1 year" # default was: "over 1 year"
        other: "%{count} years" # default was: "over %{count} years"
      almost_x_years:
        one:   "1 year" # default was: "almost 1 year"
        other: "%{count} years" # default was: "almost %{count} years"
```

Comment: You sir are a Legend

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this.